# jqgrid form post to webservice datetime changed format

Tags: datetime, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid, asmx, datetimepicker

I'm not sure whether this is related to jqgrid or is a webservice/postback/JSON issue, but I'll try to give as much information as I can.

I am posting the jqgrid's modal popup with the DateTime field .

When it posts back from the browser it submits the following data (as seen in Firebug):

```
InStock Yes
Name    Desktop Computer
Note    note
Ship    4
ShipDate    05-11-2013
id  1
oper    edit



[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string UpdateOrder(DateTime ShipDate, string Name, Stock InStock,Ship Ship, string Note,int id)
{
    return "";
}
```

The colModel of jqgrid looks like ..

```
colModel:[
    {name:'Id',index:'Id', width:60, sorttype:"int", editable: false},
    {name:'ShipDate',index:'ShipDate',width:90, editable:true, sorttype:"date",unformat: pickDate},
    {name:'Name',index:'Name', width:150,editable: true,editoptions:{size:"20",maxlength:"30"}},
    {name:'InStock',index:'InStock', width:70, editable: true,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"Yes:No"},unformat: aceSwitch},
    {name:'Ship',index:'Ship', width:90, editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"4:FedEx;1:InTime;2:TNT;3:ARAMEX"}},
    {name:'Note',index:'Note', width:150, sortable:false,editable: true,edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"10"}} 
],
```

and the pickDate looks like

```
function pickDate( cellvalue, options, cell ) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(cell) .find('input[type=text]')
                .datepicker({format:'dd-mm-yyyy' , autoclose:true}); 
    }, 0);
}
```

Also the edit form style is as follows (when edit form shows up)

```
function style_edit_form(form) {
    //enable datepicker on "sdate" field and switches for "stock" field
    form.find('input[name=ShipDate]').datepicker({format:'dd-mm-yyyy' , autoclose:true})
        .end().find('input[name=stock]')
                .addClass('ace ace-switch ace-switch-5').wrap('<label class="inline" />').after('<span class="lbl"></span>');
```

**However when the data is received at the server (asmx service), the datetime (ShipDate) changes to "11/05/2013 00:00:00" whereas the shipdate sent from the client is 05-11-2013 (which is correct). Any idea what's happening?**

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: apologies about this, the question is highlighted in bold.

Answer (score 1):

For datepicker you are using '**dd-mm-yyyy**' format but on server side it converting to different format according to culture installed i.e. '**mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss**' with the time.
If you need the same format what you are passing from jquery you need to parse the date on server side in specified format.

```
DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime("11/05/2013 00:00:00"); 
Console.WriteLine(time); //Default format 
string format = "d/M/yyyy";    // Use this format
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format));
```

Comment: I sort of understand what you are saying here. Could you please put an example?

Comment: I have placed both server side and client and server side code. I cant think of anything else to place here. Let me know if you are looking for something specific.

Comment: @user25018 i have updated my answer with the sample code for converting the desired date format you have mentioned.